# Asynchronous waiting with subprocessing?

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I have a function in a Tkinter script that utilizes `subprocess.Popen.wait()` that keeps freezing my GUI. After going through some docs ([1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) and [2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.create_subprocess_exec)), I found that I need to use `asyncio` to solve this via asynchronous waiting but I am rather confused:

> Note: The function is implemented using a busy loop (non-blocking call
> and short sleeps). Use the asyncio module for an asynchronous wait:
> see asyncio.create_subprocess_exec.

Does this mean that I have to create a subprocess for my wait() function?

Also, here's what I have so far:

```py
def foo(self)
    try:
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "someModule.py"])
        try:
            self.proc.wait(11) # <-- freezes GUI
        except Exception as l:
            someFunc()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Note: the TimeoutException catch on wait() serves as an indicator for another function to begin execution, whereas successful execution of wait() (i.e., a return value of 0) is for the opposite. Further, my goal is to have a timer in my Tkinter script activated upon successful execution of the child process, which as aforementioned, is indicated by a TimeoutException. The Tkinter interface will always be running whereas the child process will only start on user input and, similarly, end on user input (or if it unexpectedly crashes).

Edit: `someModule.py` is a script that activates an external data collecting bluetooth device. It must (1) establish a connection to the device, and if (1) is successful then (2) begin collecting data. Function (1) will wait 10 seconds for a connection to the bluetooth device to be established. If after 10 seconds a connection is not made, `someModule.py` (i.e., the child process) prints an error and **terminates**. This is why wait() executes for 11 seconds.

How do I implement asynchronous waiting?

Comment: Waiting blocks, yes. What should happen instead? What do you want to happen while the process runs / when it terminates?

Comment: Did you try to execute `foo()` in a thread?

Comment: @john-hen Thanks for the feedback. I'm not quite sure I fully understand what you are implying by this; are you saying that the except block will ALWAYS be executed, or that I should specify TimeoutExpired as the exception to catch? If it is the former, then that is incorrect because when wait() has a return value of 0 (zero), the except block is not entered.

Comment: @MaxNoe See the edit.

Comment: ``tkinter`` is a different "kind" of asynchronous than ``asyncio``. One cannot directly use the two together. You will have to write your own busy loop that uses ``tkinter``'s kind of sleeping.

Comment: @acw1668 I haven't. I'll give that a shot and get back to you soon, thanks!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi could you elaborate on this with any documentation you can refer me to?

Comment: @john-hen Hopefully my new edit clears things up, please read it. Also, when wait() does not throw an exception (or more specifically, it executes fully as a result of `someModule.py`'s termination), it does in fact seem to have a return code of 0 when I print it out with a simple `p = self.proc.wait(11)` ==> `print(p)` (output: 0). Thanks for your help so far, please let me know your thoughts!

Comment: @acw1668 That worked! Having a facepalm moment right now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: executing foo() via a [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) solved the GUI freezing problem.

```
import threading

def thread(self):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo)
    t1.start() # will terminate independently upon completion of foo()
```